# Whenever i try to render my video its just all white?

Tags: rendering

Whenever i try to render my video its just all white?
Here is a photo of my test render:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, set your exposure and gamma to 1:

[image]

Then you have a complete powerful sun (strenght 1.0) with a complete powerful environment lighting (strenght 1.0) resulting in too much light!
This is a test render with both set to 0.1.

[image]

Lighting is very complex and very powerful, so .... good luck!